# Why is my PHP contact form is sending emails with the body (message) blank?

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I am a complete PHP newbie. I have a contact form which is sending me the email upon submitting the form, but the body of the email is completely empty. Everything I've tried or looked up/researched online has not worked. I have no idea what is wrong with my code. As I mentioned before, I have no idea what I'm doing with this PHP (HTML and CSS are about all I can handle). I apologize in advance, I need a serious amount of handholding to fix this! If someone could help me with this I would be eternally grateful. Please and thank you! My code is pasted below, I've changed the email address's for security reasons. Also, we are running the latest version of php on our web server's as well, if that helps.

**My HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
        <form action="BRF-sendForm.php" method="post" enctype="x-www-form-encoded">
            <table width="647" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
                <tr align="middle" valign="middle">
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;"><strong>Biography Request Form</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td width="40%">*First Name</td>
                    <td width="60%"><input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Middle Name<br />
                        (If you would like it to appear)</td>
                    <td><input name="MiddleName" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>*Last Name</td>
                    <td><input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>*Email</td>
                    <td><input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td><input name="Title" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Organization</td>
                    <td><input name="Organization" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Years in Current Role</td>
                    <td><input name="Years in Current Role" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Role/Responsibilities</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="4" name="Role/Responsibilities" />
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Credentials</td>
                    <td><input name="Credentials" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Years Experience</td>
                    <td><input name="Years Experience" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>City and State of Residence</td>
                    <td><input name="City and State of Residence" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Notable Companies of Previous Employment<br />
                        (Include title(s) held)</td>
                    <td><textarea  rows="4" name="Notable Employment" />
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Awards (include year awarded)</td>
                    <td><textarea  rows="4" name="Awards" />
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Professional Organizations/Affiliations</td>
                    <td><input name="Professional Organizations/Affiliations" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Previous Title(s) with Current Organization (include years):</td>
                    <td><input name="Previous Title(s) with Current Organization" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="647" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="pageBreak">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"style="font-size:17px;"><br />
                        <strong>Education</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td width="40%">Name of School, College or University</td>
                    <td width="60%"><input name="School Name" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Degree</td>
                    <td><input name="Degree" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Year Completed</td>
                    <td><input name="Year Completed" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Name of School, College or University</td>
                    <td><input name="School Name" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Degree</td>
                    <td><input name="Degree" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Year Completed</td>
                    <td><input name="Year Completed" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="647" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:17px;"><br />
                        <strong>Veteran Status</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td width="40%">Branch</td>
                    <td width="60%"><input name="Branch" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Years Served</td>
                    <td><input name="Years Served" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td>Personal</td>
                    <td><textarea  rows="4" name="Personal" />
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**My PHP:**

```
    <?
ob_start();
$now = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');


if (check_data()){
    // Send E-Mail
    echo '<h1 style="margin-top: 20px; text-align:center;">Biography Request Form</h1>';

    send_mail();
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;">Thank you! Your form has been submitted.</p>';
}
else{
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;">Please correct the above errors, and submit your form again. If you are having trouble submitting this form please contact <a href="email@test.com">email@test.com</a></p>';

    exit();
}


function verifyData($str_to_test) {
  $bad_strings = array(
                "content-type:"
                ,"mime-version:"
                ,"multipart/mixed"
                ,"Content-Transfer-Encoding:"
                ,"bcc:"
                ,"cc:"
                ,"to:"
  );

  foreach($bad_strings as $bad_string) {
    if(eregi($bad_string, strtolower($str_to_test))) {
      showerror("$bad_string found. Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.");

    }
  }
}

function contains_newlines($str_to_test) {
   if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+)/i", $str_to_test) != 0) {
     showerror("newline found in $str_to_test. Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.");
     exit;
   }
} 

function check_data(){

    // also inspects data for hacking attempts (via verifyData).
    // if verifyData finds something suspicious, the page exists with a warning.
    $isok = true;
    // Check for a person's name.
    if (eregi ("^[[:alnum:].' -]{1,100}", stripslashes(trim($_POST['FirstName'])))) {
    } else {
        $isok = false;
        $errors[] = '<p style="color: #F00; text-align: center;">Please enter your first name!</p>';
    }
    if (eregi ("^[[:alnum:].' -]{1,100}", stripslashes(trim($_POST['LastName'])))) {
    } else {
        $isok = false;
        $errors[] = '<p style="color: #F00; text-align: center;">Please enter your last name!</p>';
    }
    if (eregi ("^[[:alnum:].' -]{1,100}", stripslashes(trim($_POST['Email'])))) {
    } else {
        $isok = false;
        $errors[] = '<p style="color: #F00; text-align: center;">Please enter your email!</p>';
    }
    if (!$isok){
        foreach($errors as $err)
        echo '<div>' . $err . '</div>';
        return false;
    }


    // look for hacker codes.
    verifyData($_POST['Address']);
    verifyData($_POST['City']);
    verifyData($_POST['State']);
    verifyData($_POST['State']);
    verifyData($_POST['Zip']);
    verifyData($_POST['Email']);


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){
       showerror("Unauthorized attempt to access page.");
    }
    return true;
}

function send_mail(){


    $to = 'email@test.com'; 
    $subject = "Test Mail";

    $txt = "<p>Below is the result of your feedback form.  It was submitted by</p>";
    $txt .= "<table>";
    foreach($_POST AS $field => $value) {
        if (substr($field, 0, 12) == 'Send_info_on')
            $field = 'Box checked:';
        $printIt = true;
        if (substr($field, 0, 18) == 'more_info_on_other'){
                if ($value > ' '){
                    $field = 'Box checked:';
                }else{
                    $printIt = false;
                }
        }

        if ($field == 'submit'){
            $printIt = false;
        }

        if ($printIt){
            $txt .= '<tr><td>' . $field . '&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    $txt .= '</table>';
    //echo $txt;

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: webmaster@test.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: email@test.com". "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);


}

function showerror($msg) { 
  ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sorry, Please Try Again</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#FFFFFF text=#000000>
<center>
    <table border=0 width=600 bgcolor=#9C9C9C>
        <tr>
            <th><font size=+2>Oops!</font></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=0 width=600 bgcolor=#CFCFCF>
        <tr>
            <td>Something you entered did not pass our security checks.</td>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $msg ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please check your data, then submit again.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?
ob_end_flush();
exit();

}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Your [coding style could be improved](http://www.phtml.org) and you have invalid HTML like `<textarea rows="4" name="Role/Responsibilities" />
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>
                        </textarea>`

Comment: Remove this `enctype="x-www-form-encoded"` *for one thing*

Comment: Another thing is, throughout most of your `$txt` you're using double quotes then ending with `$txt .= '<tr><td>' . $field . '&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;' . $value . '</td></tr>';` singles. This is a debug/formatting issue. High performance car with an inexperienced driver behind the wheel; bound to smash into a tree in the next curve.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, thanks for catching that. That was a really dumb mistake. I've been so focused on the php trying to figure it out and didn't really take a good look at my form page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the quotes are correct in the code shown above, ther eis not debug/formatting kind of issue. But here is a semicolon missing: `<? echo $msg ?>` after `$msg`, also short_open_tags are deprecated because they are off by default in most configurations

Comment: I've given up on this question @DanFromGermany

Comment: @Fred-ii- I like your high performance car comparisson tho, it's really true for most people asking here in PHP tag haha

Comment: hahaha, I knew "someone" would get a kick out of that! Here's another: "This script is like a VCR, too many moving parts". Meaning, too many things happening, and bound to go wrong hehe - Glad I was able to entertain ;-) @DanFromGermany guten tag

Comment: And it's so true. How many times have I seen (*and you I'm sure*) these **"blow me away" scripts** where people have no idea as to what they do, or how they work, and expect us to fix it. @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 0):

How many  you are closing??

```
   <textarea rows="4" name="Role/Responsibilities" />
                    </textarea>
                    </textarea>
                    </textarea>
```

Comment: *"Rows is not a valid attribute"* Really? Did you not visit the link yourself? - *"rows = valid non-negative integer - 
Specifies the number of lines to show. by defult, it is 2."* and for the life of me, that page URL has a spelling mistake `defult` too funny.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: HTML attributes are case-sensitive. But you're right, that shouldn't cause any errors and should work perfectly fine. :)

Comment: Um... what is the relevance of `case`? And the only thing I can see as being invalid is the `/` in `name="Role/Responsibilities"` @AmalMurali or was that what you were referring to?